# Variable from attribute only displays the first word

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a listview which is dynamically populated with offers for a store locator I am developing. The listview populates perfectly fine with a formatted list with the offer title and offer description.

I am trying to create a saved feature where the user can save offers for offline use. To do this I am transferring the database values into attributes of the dynamic listview where I can place them into variables for use in sessions/localstorage etc.

Here is my js code that defines the attributes and displays the listview.

```
var output1 = '';                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
function getoffers(data) {                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    var data = JSON.parse(data);                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    console.log(data);                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    $.each(data, function(index, value){        
        output1 += '<li offertitle='+value.offer_title+' offer-desc='+value.offer_desc+' offer-expiry='+value.expiry_date+'><a href="#""><h1>'+value.offer_title+'</h1><p>'+value.offer_desc+'</p><p class="ui-li-aside"><b>Expiry Date:</b>'+value.expiry_date+'</p></a></li>';                                                                                                                       
    });                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    $('#offerlist').html(output1).listview().listview('refresh');                                                                                                                                                                     
}
```

As you can see, I display the database values **and** assign them to attributes in their dynamic listview row.

I create the variables on click of the listview row where I alert each variable for testing. This is where I discover that the variable only has the first word (of what should be a paragraph).

Eg. An offer that should say "Buy one, get one free". Only returns "Buy" in the variable.

```
$("#offers ul").on("click", ">li", function(event, ui) {                                                                                                                                                                           
    var offertitle = $(this).closest('li').attr('offertitle'); 
    var offerdesc = $(this).closest('li').attr('offer-desc');
    var offerexpiry = $(this).closest('li').attr('offer-expiry'); 

    alert(offertitle);
    alert(offerdesc);
    alert(offerexpiry);                                                                                                                                                                                       
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not quoting the attribute, so only the first word is treated as part of it.

You need to set it like:

```
output1 += '<li offertitle="'+value.offer_title+'" offer-desc="'+value.offer_desc+'" offer-expiry="'+value.expiry_date+'"><a href="#""><h1>'+value.offer_title+'</h1><p>'+value.offer_desc+'</p><p class="ui-li-aside"><b>Expiry Date:</b>'+value.expiry_date+'</p></a></li>';
```

As an aside, you shouldn't be defining your own custom attributes, but rather using [HTML data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes).

Comment: much appreciated my friend. I will remove the custom attributes also. Thanks again.